# Rename files in assemble task in gradle

Tags: gradle

I need to write a simple task to create a zip from the source code. I need to include a dir called *1-dir* or *2-dir* depending on a system property. But the name of the directory in the resulting zip should always be *dir*. So basically, I want to include a dir in a zip (conditionally) and rename it.

I tried the rename method but that does not work. 
Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

It will be:

```
task zipDir(type: Zip) {
   def fromDir = project.hasProperty('from') ? project.from : 'dir1'
   from(fromDir)
   into('dir')
}
```

It can be run in the following way `gradle zipDir -Pfrom=dir2`. If no `from` property is passed `dir1` will be zipped.

If you need system property instead of gradle property, pass `-Dfrom=dir2` and use `System.properties['from']` instead of `project.from`.